# Docker, Kafka - replication doesn't work between remote brokers

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

Have docker images of kafka brokers and zookeeper - call them `z1, b1, b2` for now.
They are deployed on two physical servers `s1` and `s2` as so:
`s1` contains `z1` and `b1`
`s2` contains `b2`

In their own `docker-compose.yml` files, zookeeper has set ports as following:

```
- 2181:2181
- 2888:2888
- 3888:3888
```

and brokers as following:

```
- 9092:9092
```

Topic with `--replication-factor 2` and `--partitions 4` can be created.
No data are pushed to topic for whole time, but still following problem occurs.
If `kafka-topics --describe --topic <name_of_topic> --zookeeper <zookeeperIP:port>` is run shortly after topic creation, all is `insync` and looks good.
 On second run (with short delay), `b1` removes `b2` partitions replicas from it's `insync`, but `b2` doesn't remove `b1` partitions replicas from `insync`.

In server.log from `b1`, there are showing many of these exceptions:

```
WARN [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-1], Error in fetch kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread$FetchRequest@42746de3 (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to ef447651b07a:9092 (id: 1 rack: null) failed
    at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.awaitReady$1(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:83)
    at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.blockingReady$extension(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:93)
    at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.sendRequest(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:248)
    at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.fetch(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:238)
    at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.fetch(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:42)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.processFetchRequest(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:118)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.doWork(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:103)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:63)
```

Swapping leadership works between brokers `b1` and `b2`, as they are shut down and started again, but then only the last one online is in full control of topic - is leader for all partitions and only one `insync`, even if the other broker comes back online.

Tried cleaning all data, reseting both brokers and zookeeper, but problem persists.

Why partitions aren't properly replicated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There was problem with network, as Michael G. Noll said.
Firstly, I don't map ports manually anymore and use `host` network instead. It's easier to manage.
Secenodary, b1 and b2 had listeners set like so:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
```

They both had no ip specified, so `0.0.0.0` was used by default and there was collission, as they both listened there and pushed same connection information to zookeeper.

**Final configuration**:
`b1` and `b2` `docker-compose.yml` use `host` network:

```
network_mode: "host"
```

`b1` server.properties` - listeners:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://<s1_IP>:9092
```

`b2` server.properties` - listeners:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://<s2_IP>:9092
```

Everything works fine now, replication is working, even on broker restarts.
Data can be produced and consumed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the brokers `b1` and `b2` can't talk to each other, which indicates a Docker-related networking issue (and such Docker networking issues are quite common in general).

You'd need to share more information for further help, e.g. the contents of the `docker-compose.yml` file(s) as well as e.g. the `Dockerfile` you use to create your images.  I also wonder why you have created different images for the two brokers, typically you only need a single Kafka broker image, and then simply launch multiple containers (one per desired broker) off of that image.

Comment: Thanks for response. I can't paste docker files here; and it would be pointless as only network settings matter now. Ports in docker-compose.yml are mapped as mentioned in question, zookeepers client port is set to 2181; and both kafka brokers have listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092. I also tried not to specify ip and change ports so brokers were mapped to 0.0.0.0:9092 and 0.0.0.0:9093, but issue still persists. Also read about REPLICATION listener - should it be set as I have only PLAINTEXT specified ?

Comment: What's your environment?  Do you run this e.g. locally on a Mac or inside Kubernetes?  Are you using docker-machine w/ a Linux VM, or ...? This impacts how Docker's networking functions. Also, it would not be pointless to show docker files because you keep asking questions about Docker settings, and it's hard to help you debug when you can't see the full picture -- e.g. host network mode or bridge network mode? how do you set the `hostname` of containers?